# Github Actions workflow throwing this error 'Could not resolve package dependencies Package.swift manifest for version 1.4.2'

Tags: xcode, continuous-integration, github-actions, swift-package-manager

I have a github-action configuration setup for an iOS App, with the following declaration in my CI.yml file:

```
    name: BuildAndTestCI
    on:
      pull_request:
        branches: [master]
    
    jobs:
      build-and-test:
        runs-on: macos-latest
        steps:
        - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    
        - name: Select Xcode
          run: sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode_11.3.app
    
        - name: Build and Test
          run: xcodebuild clean build test -project sample/sample.xcodeproj -scheme "sample" -sdk iphonesimulator -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (5th generation)" ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO
```

But the workflow run and stop with the following error:

```
xcodebuild: error: Could not resolve package dependencies:
  https://github.com/Juanpe/SkeletonView.git has no Package.swift manifest for version 1.4.2
```

The possible solutions that I've tried are:

1. Reset package caches
2. Upgrade the affected packages 'SkeletonView'
3. Perform a global search where 1.4.2 appears (no-where)
4. Build and Clean the project multiple times

Also my concerns are:

1. There is no package that has the version number 1.4.2 and yet the Github-Action Workflow still throws the said error every time a build process is triggered via commit.
2. There is absolutely no way to do a proper debugging, and I feel like I'm stuck

Below is the full logs of the Github-Action Workflow:

```
**Set up a job**
Current runner version: '2.284.0'
Operating System
Virtual Environment
Virtual Environment Provisioner
GITHUB_TOKEN Permissions
Prepare workflow directory
Prepare all required actions
Getting action download info
Download action repository 'actions/checkout@v2' (SHA:ec3a7ce113134d7a93b817d10a8272cb61118579)


**Run actions/checkout@v2**

Run actions/checkout@v2
Syncing repository: repository/sample-ios
Getting Git version info
Deleting the contents of '/Users/runner/work/sample-ios/sample-ios'
Initializing the repository
Disabling automatic garbage collection
Setting up auth
Fetching the repository
Determining the checkout info
Checking out the ref
/usr/local/bin/git log -1 --format='%H'
'9ebab3de7d5294064240e266cb4070a52e08c672'

**Select Xcode**

Run sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode_11.3.app

**Build and test**

Run xcodebuild clean build test -project sample/sample.xcodeproj -scheme "sample" -sdk iphonesimulator -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (5th generation)" ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO
Build settings from command line:
    CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED = NO
    ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH = NO
    SDKROOT = iphonesimulator13.2

Resolve Package Graph

Fetching https://github.com/Juanpe/SkeletonView.git

Fetching https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-ios.git

Fetching https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk.git

Fetching https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-cocoa

Fetching https://github.com/intercom/intercom-ios

xcodebuild: error: Could not resolve package dependencies:
  https://github.com/Juanpe/SkeletonView.git has no Package.swift manifest for version 1.4.2

Error: Process completed with exit code 74.
```